# Script to extract unique values in each line of a large file

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a large csv file, resembling this:

```
222,333,222,333,444
777,333,222,555,777
...
```

I need to make it such that duplicates in each line are removed:

```
222,333,444
777,333,222,555
```

I wrote this piece of script for the purpose:

```
for line in `cat a.txt`; do echo $line | tr ',' '\n' | sort | uniq | tr '\n' ','  ; echo ; done
```

This works, but I think there is an easier way.

Is there a way to achieve this using the command line (on Unix) without having to write a loop in a script? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: On SO we encourage users to add their efforts in their question, could you please add the same and let us know then.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13; I have done the needful.

Comment: Could you please check my solution once and let me know if that helps you?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have much better luck with awk than with your pipeline. It would be lovely to see what you've done yourself with awk, so that we could help you through any challenges you're facing. Failing that, here's how I'd approach this:

```
# Set our field separators
BEGIN { OFS=FS="," }

{
  # Initialize variables...
  delete a; x=0

  # Step through the line...
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    # Record "seen" values in an array, but if they're unseen,
    if (!a[$i]++) {
      # Print the field (possible with a separator)
      if (x++) printf "%s", OFS
      printf "%s", $i
    }
  }

  # End the line
  print ""
}
```

Note that the only purpose of the `x` variable is to determine whether we need to print the field separator.

If you test this on a large file, I'd love to know how it compares speed-wise to your pipeline solution.